# startdate openssl set timezone

Tags: date, timezone, openssl

Good Morning,

Today I have a question concerning openssl. When I sign a certificat in openssl with my CA, I realized that I needed to wait a certain amount of time before being able to use the certificat.

At first I did not understant what was wrong as I had the same hour on my ca and on my server (Used for openvpn). But I realized that when you sign a certificat by default the timezone of the certificate is GMT while my server are using CET.

So I thought that I was going to use startdate when I generate the certificate and the problème will be solwed. But even when I use start date like '20140404000000Z' , the time zone is still GMT while my server is in CET.

Is it possible to tell him to use the timezone of my server and not GMT. My server is a centos.

Any help would be appricated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [RFC 5280](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt) which defines X.509 certificate profile the time fields in the certificate MUST be expressed in GMT time. See sections 4.1.2.5, 4.1.2.5.1 and 4.1.2.5.2.

Anyway when your server verifies validity of the client certificate it should transform GMT time acquired from certificate to its own timezone or vice versa. Maybe the clock on the system where you are issuing certificates is not in sync with the clock on your VPN server? Even few seconds or minutes can make difference.

Comment: Thanks for your response, actually I realised that there is a small difference between my server, I will update them with ntpdate.